# Is it possible to create multiple objects in the same form based on selected HTML elements in Rails 4?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is the scenario:

Let's say you have a calendar app, where you want to add an event to multiple days. Ideally you would just click on the days you wanted to add the event to. Then you would fill out a form with the event name and the start and end time of the event and then Rails would automatically add the event to all the selected days.

I have 3 models: A CalendarPeriod model, a Weekday model and an Event model.
They are linked together as follows:

```
class CalendarPeriod < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :weekdays
end

class Weekday < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar_period
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :weekday
end
```

CalendarPeriod has :start_time and :end_time attributes.

Weekday has a :date attribute.

Event has :start_time and :end_time attributes as well.

All of the attributes are of the type datetime and the foreign keys are also handled correctly.

I have a form that generates a CalendarPeriod based on the :start_time and :end_time attributes. In the create action I also generate a Weekday for each day in the CalendarPeriod. All of this works fine. I then have a view that renders a "calendar" based on CalendarPeriod and its associated weekdays.

**My question is:**

Is it possible to generate a form that lets me create multiple events at the same time, based on how many weekdays I have clicked on? I thought about using JavaScript to add a class to every weekday-element I clicked on and then use AJAX to render the form that creates events. Is this possible? If so, please share your thoughts on how I would be able to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)
Here is a good screencast to understand [screencast](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/nested-forms-from-scratch)

This should work for the thing you want to implement.

Include

> gem "nested_form"

in your Gemfile.

If you're using asset pipeline, add following line in your application.js

> //= require jquery_nested_form

Give associations like this,
**calendar_period.rb**

```
has_many :weekdays, dependent: :destroy<br />
has_many :events, :through => :weekdays

accepts_nested_attributes_for :weekdays
accepts_nested_attributes_for :events
```

**weekday.rb**

```
belongs_to :calendar_period
has_many :events, dependent: :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :events
```

**event.rb**

```
belongs_to :weekday
```

Create your form object as below:
**calendar_period_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @calendar_period = CalendarPeriod.new
    @weekday = @calendar_period.weekdays.build
    @event = @weekday.events.build
end

def calendar_period_params
    params.require(:calendar_period).permit(:start_time, :end_time,
     weekdays_attributes: [:id, :param1, :param2,
     events_attributes: [:id, :start_time, :end_time]]) 
end
```

Make your form like below:

```
<%= nested_form_for @calendar_period do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :start_time %>
    <%= f.link_to_add "Add weekday", :weekdays %>
    <%= f.fields_for :weekdays do |weekdays_form| %>
        <%= weekdays_form.text_field param1 %>
        <%= weekdays_form.link_to_add "Add event", :events %>
        <%= weekdays_form.fields_for do |events_form| %>
            <%= events_form.text_field :start_time %>
            <%= events_form.link_to_remove "Remove this event" %>
        <% end %>
        <%= weekdays_form.link_to_remove "Remove this weekday" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Arth. It was not exactly what I was looking for, but I'll mark it as an answer because it's pretty similiar to the way I'm going to solve this. For anyone wondering: I'll create a form for every weekday, in which I can create events. Upon creating the event I'll save the form values as JS variables and set the rest of the form attributes to the same values. The forms will use AJAX to prevent page reload. This way every form will have the same values as the last one by default, which makes it easier to create new events with the same values.

Comment: @TobiasKristensen cool thanks, it sounds interesting. Please share the JS and Ajax code samples of your solution as a reference, if possible.